# What is the maximum character I should limit per a chat message?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, chat

I am writing a chat application on Android and iOS that can send only between mobile using Socket.io and firebase. My question is, are there any references to show the maximum length of the characters per message in the case to set its limit.

I try to find the reference, but no one relates to my question yet.

Example: https://gyazo.com/de4b2c90b79fd585b7bcc4037e0abecf

Comment: Please share pic. or something for better understanding.

Comment: @EmreCiftci https://gyazo.com/de4b2c90b79fd585b7bcc4037e0abecf Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Messaging? If you're using that to send chat messages then each Firebase Message has a maximum of 4kb of data, **or** a 1024 character limit for message sent from the Firebase Console.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

- Maximum payload for messages is 4KB.
- Firebase console enforces a 1024 character limit.

Enforcing your own maximum character count is likely the best solution in this scenario. You can figure this out by knowing that a single character is 1 byte and 1024 characters is 1kb.

Comment: More common text encodings like UTF 8 can be more than one byte per character. ASCII would fit your model but that's a very limiting encoding.

Comment: @JakeB I use firebase in case only to send a notification, but for the text message is via Socket.

Answer (score 0):

depend on the framework/sdk you are using,there is no standardisation for it